# SQL: Extracting with Percentage of Unit Counts

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I need a report showing the percentage of its unit count for a day/month/year depending on the date range.

I tried this in PostgreSQL but it doesn't give result that I want.

```
SELECT "Code"
    ,"UnitCount"
    ,"UnitCount"::FLOAT * 100 / (sum("UnitCount") OVER (PARTITION BY user)) AS "Percent1"
    ,("UnitCount" / (sum("UnitCount")) * 100) AS "Percent1"
FROM (
    SELECT "Code"
        ,Count("ID") AS "UnitCount"
    FROM "TableName"
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '20150227'
            AND '20150227'
    GROUP BY "Code"
    ) x
```

Expected Result with the *formula* : **UnitCount / OverAllUnitCount * 100**

> **UnitCount** = Counts for each Code of the date range
>
> **OverAllUnitCount** = Counts for all Code of the date range

Query for PostgeSQL and MySQL will do please.
Thanks so much! :D

Please see image to view sample and expected result:
[image]

Comment: Can you show sample input and expected output ??

Comment: @wingedpanther: I already included it in my question. Thanks

Comment: In the subquery you are calculating `"UnitCount"` as `Count("ID")` which is = 3 for both `Code0001` and `Code0002` values for your sample input. But it seems that you need not counting but summing for output your expect. So, in the squbquery change `,Count("ID") AS "UnitCount"` to `,sum("ID") AS "UnitCount"`